# Java String of hex to byte []

Tags: java, byte

It's need to convert string like:

```
String test = "0xF0 0x9F 0x87 0xB7 0xF0 0x9F 0x87 0xBA";
String [] GetByte = test.split(" ");
```

to byte array like:

```
byte [] test_arr = new byte [GetByte.length];
        test [0] = (byte) 0xF0;
        test [1] = (byte) 0x9F;
        test [2] = (byte) 0x87;
        test [3] = (byte) 0xB7;
        test [4] = (byte) 0xF0;
        test [5] = (byte) 0x9F;
        test [6] = (byte) 0x87;
        test [7] = (byte) 0xBA;
```

Any one can help? Thanks!

Comment: Tried anything yet?

Comment: Since this is a somewhat cumbersome conversion (but definitely doable) is there some other format to get the string in? I am thinking of something like Base64 encoding.

Comment: no other format

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] words = test.split(" ");
byte[] bytes = new byte[words.length];
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
    //bytes[i] = Byte.decode(words[i]);
    bytes[i] = Integer.decode(words[i]).byteValue();
}
```

The method `decode` would also translate other bases.

Unfortunately `byte` is signed, so `0xF0` overflows, `Byte.decode` cannot be used.

Comment: I had hoped that in java 8 finally `Byte.decode` would work on 0xF0 (240 > Byte.MAX_VALUE == 127). Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integer[] numbers =
    //splitting the string into an array and converting it to a stream
    Arrays.stream(test.split(" "))
        //removing '0x' from each hex string and parsing an integer value from it
        .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s.replace("0x", ""), 16))
        //collecting everything to an integer array
        .toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

I've added some comments about how this code works.

The reason why I used integers instead of bytes is that there are some hex values in the given string that overflow byte.

Comment: Although this is an answer to the question, might be better to just provide some textual explanation of what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're 100% sure that each number begins with `0x`, then you can substring that out, then parse it using `Integer.parseInt(substringed, 16)`.

Comment: get error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x"

Comment: i need to somehow to cast String 0xF0 as byte (byte)0xF0

Comment: You must have done `.substring(0,2)` which is exactly the "0x" part you **don't** want.  The digits you want to parse would be `.substring(2,4)`